# What is a "category"?

Tags: category-theory

I have tried to understand category theory for a while but never been able to get it. I finally found a text I like called Category Theory for Scientists. However, I think it would be easier to read this text if I knew roughly what category theory is about. Since I'm new to SE, I thought I'd come here and see if I can get some help before trying again.

Can someone summarize a few of the most important, elementary concepts in category theory? For example, what is a "category"?

Thanks!

Comment: The text itself really should start by providing such a definition -- or you should seriously reconsider your decision to like it.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics), there, there is a good start

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Cat-E-Gory-Edward-Gorey/dp/0915361558

Comment: MSE is not a place to ask for definitions.

Answer (score 2):

In math we often have objects and special functions between them.  For example:

- Sets and all functions
- Vector spaces and linear transformations
- Groups and homomorphisms
- Topological spaces and continuous maps

That's basically all a category is.  You have objects and you have morphisms (the functions).

Comment: Okay. That's what I thought. Glad I asked. Thanks!

Comment: and the morphisms can be composed when their domain and codomain match, and the composition is associative, and there are identity morphisms which behave like identities for the composition (and morphisms don't need to be functions at all).

Comment: That's so... vague... Is that what makes category theory useful?

Comment: @IttayWeiss nice! Didn't know that either.

Comment: Yes, there's more to the definition, this is only the basic idea.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Math is really about relationships between various objects, and category theory has a lot of flexibility in describing those relationships.  There aren't just arrows between objects, there are functors between categories, natural transformations between functors.  And the vagueness allows you to do things like define categories whose objects are the arrows from another category, or the functors between certain categories, and talk about functors and natrual transformations involving *those*, and so on and so forth.

Comment: @Jim Are there any notable theorems proven with category theory? (Notable theorems whose statements don't involve category-theoretic definitions.)

Comment: There are some examples of theorems that have come out of categorification, but the math there gets hard, I can't claim to understand it.  More often what you find is that category theory is a great shorthand for complicated math.  For example there are tons of constructions in topology or algebra where you could either give a long detailed description of a bunch of properties or you could just write down a diagram, tell people it's a pullback, and be done with it.  Universal properties are another good example of this.